# Npgsql "The operation has timed out." when replacing underlying RDS instance

Tags: npgsql, rds, amazon-ecs

We are experiencing what I believe to be an issue with connection pooling when using Amazon RDS database instances to back our web application running on ECS.

Using https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL ("Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.1.0").

The error specifically occurs when we roll-back the RDS instance to a previous point in time. The connection string remains unchanged, but I suspect the Npgsql driver believes it still has active connections open, even though they have been terminated server side (by the rollback).

Restarting our application obviously fixes the problem as it creates new connections after launch, but is an undesirable solution.

Is this a bug within Npgsql? Should it be timing out on a connection that has been forcibly closed? Maybe there is something we can put in the connection string to force it to retry? (Although I'd like to avoid turning off connection pooling completely if possible.)

Comment: AFAIK Npgsql 2.0.x suffered the same problem. This has Nothing to do with Amazon RDS. You could propbably confirm the issue while connected to a local instance, Killing some of the pooled connection server side.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierMATROT have confirmed that. Is there any work arounds you are aware of? Outside of cycling the "client" application?

Comment: No, you should open an issue on github.